# Use jquery function in vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Trying to figure out how to use Jquery function in vuejs method. Im trying to use fadeOut() function, but that dont work, because I think I need to use jquery object. I tried something, but that doesnt working. Any ideas how to do that and that is possible?

```
<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        removeParticipant(participant_id) {
            axios.post('/api/tournament/removeParticipant', {
                tourn_id: {{ $tournament->id }},
                participant_id: participant_id
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.data == 'ok') {
                    $ele = window.$(this);
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                    alert($ele);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial about how to include jQuery in a Vue project. I have read that it is not recommended, but it can be done. https://maketips.net/tip/223/how-to-include-jquery-into-vuejs Let me know if it works.

Comment: Typically you don't want to run code that exists outside of Vue because Vue's change detection logic loses context as to whats going on and wipes out what jQuery does/did.

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't be mixing Vue and jQuery is you simply want to remove something onclick. set a data property to false onclick and the element you want to hide use v-if="dataproperty"

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to fadeOut the div with id #app ?, if so try to use this code.
after vue initialization get the element and store it in a variable like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
},
mounted() {

},
methods: {
    removeParticipant(participant_id) {
        axios.post('/api/tournament/removeParticipant', {
            tourn_id: {{ $tournament->id }},
            participant_id: participant_id
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.data == 'ok') {
                //$ele = window.$(this); ///////comment this section
                $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                alert($ele);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
});

var $ele = $('#app');//////////////declare your variable after vue initialization
```

Comment: Nop, I want use **this** to see which button was clicked, called that function and then just remove div from html with jquery help.